# Define a struct that contains a function pointer to a function that takes the struct as an argument

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers

Is the following struct definition safe?

```
typedef struct s_foo {
  void (*func)(s_foo);
  /* A few other fields */
} foo;
```

I need to able to store pointers in it to functions of the form

```
void function_name(foo f){
    /* Use f.func and other fields. */
}
```

So two things: is it OK to use `s_foo` instead of `foo`, and is it OK to use the struct in itself as long as it's in a function pointer? I know it's OK to use pointers to the struct, but I've never seen anything like this. (I simplified the code for posting; I promise that in my application this is necessary!)

Note: because `foo` is so small, I really want to pass it by value into `function_name`. My `function_name` functions are performance critical, and an unnecessary pointer dereference would be a big deal. I'm really just trying to package together three arguments as one.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The problem is that I need to use this in extremely performance-critical applications, where dereferencing the extra pointer would be really wasteful. And since it's such a tiny struct, I want to be able to pass it by value.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I have a good reason... think of it as a theoretical question if you must :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You don't have to fully define a struct to declare a function taking it as an argument.

Comment: Then *measure* it first. Even if it's performance critical, using pointers is negligible using modern compilers and platforms. And remember that if you pass "by value" then the whole structure is *copied* which of course creates a performance hit.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The structure has only three fields, all of which are pointers. It's definitely faster to do it this way. And I can't measure it if I can't compile it!

Comment: so this  question was about compilation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this code is fine in principle. Just you are misusing the C namespaces. This is why `typedefs` are kind of misleading and IMO should be used very sparingly. It greatly confuses namespace understanding.

In your example you have declared a function pointer such as `void (*func)(s_foo);`. There is no such thing as an `s_foo` in your program for the function to take as an argument, only a `struct s_foo` these are different things in different namespaces.

Try this, without the typedefs to confuse things it should work fine.:

```
struct foo {
  void (*func)(struct foo);
  /* A few other fields */
};

void function_name(struct foo f){
    /* Use f.func and other fields. */
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how I'm misusing namespaces? Apologies, am n00b.

Comment: There's no need to predeclare `struct foo;` separately. Once you are inside the actual `struct foo` declaration, `struct foo` is already known as a type (albeit not yet complete).

Comment: @AnT Thanks, I wasnt 100% sure and didnt have time to check my C99 spec so went the safe route. Removed it.

Comment: But I can use typedef, right? As long as I predeclare it?

Comment: @RenéG What do you mean exactly? I think you could do: `struct foo; typedef struct foo bar; struct foo {void (*func)(bar); };` but it starts to get very ugly... And honestly feels more like its within the scope of a new question.

Comment: @René G: Yes. Mentioning it inside `typedef` already predeclares it. No need for a separate declaration. `typedef struct foo foo; struct foo { void (*func)(foo); };`.

Comment: @ant I notice you use the same name for the struct and type. In the codebase I'm working on, they use 's_foo' for the struct and 'foo' for the type. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: @René G: I'm not aware of any credible reason for this. However, some people prefer different names for struct *tags* and typedef-ed struct *types*. In any case, there's absolutely nothing illegal in using identical names in both places.